# Customize Error Reporting via E-mail in Pylons

Tags: email, reporting, pylons, customization

I am sending myself WebApp error reports from Pylons when users hit critical errors and I would love to be able to get the full output of session[] in the reports and customize it to my liking, but I've got no idea how to do that, or where the report is actually created / put together.

Anyone know how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank Michael for answering me, without really giving me anything to build on.  That meant I had to figure it out myself, and that's always a good thing :)

What I did was, I looked at /config/middleware.py in my Pylons project and found this line:

```
app = ErrorHandler(app, global_conf, **config['pylons.errorware'])
```

I made my own ErrorHandler def and my own ErrorMiddleware class at the top of the middleware.py file:

```
class ClaraErrorMiddleware(ErrorMiddleware):
    def exception_handler(self, exc_info, environ):
        # do what ever you want with the exc_info or environ vars
        super(ClaraErrorMiddleware, self).exception_handler(exc_info, environ) # call parent
    pass

def ClaraErrorHandler(app, global_conf, **errorware):
    if asbool(global_conf.get('debug')):
        return ErrorHandler(app, global_conf, **errorware)
    else:
        return ClaraErrorMiddleware(app, global_conf, **errorware)
```

So now, I can throw in some extra variables I want to be sent with my error emails.  Simple enough ...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you will have to roll your own for this functionality. WebError is the package used to handle this, and it doesn't provide any extension points. Your best bet may be to use a fork of it with your changes, although even then the code is not pretty.